# Can a Master's program be continued at a university in another country?

Tags: thesis, masters, international-students, biotechnology, norway

I am working on my Master's in Norway as an international student.  Unfortunately, international students aren't allowed more than 3 years for a Master's in Norway, but I've only completed 60 of the required 120 credit hours.

Since I can't finish the degree in Norway, I'm trying to see if I could continue working on a Master's in another country without losing current degree progress.  In particular, I still need to complete a thesis.

Would it be possible to finish up the Master's degree program in another country given Norway's limitation on international students?

Comment: The question was unclear, so I applied a speculative edit.  Please feel free to edit it to match your intent!

Comment: Looking back at this, did you mean that your'e a PhD student rather than a Master's?  I mean the original question explicitly said it was a Master's and used the "_[tag:masters]_" tag, but this would make a lot more sense if it were about a PhD.  At least in the US, 60 credits tends to be sufficient for a Master's, while 120 is closer to a PhD, where the difference is typically filled with research credit hours during which a student does a dissertation (or perhaps "_thesis_" in the above?).  That said, it'd be weird if students were allowed a maximum of 3 years for a PhD.

Answer (score 2):

In all universities I've ever had acquaintance with: **No**. A Master's program at another university cannot be continued. I believe this is almost universally true, but that's speculation.

On the other hand, there is a chance you might be allowed to start a Master's program, get credit for many of the courses you've already taken (for some definition of "many"...), and continue the same research you've worked on - so that the duplicate work you would do would be reduced. This is much more likely if you **find a prospective advisor/supervisor** who would be willing to take you on and promote your admission and requests.